# How can I create an array of functions?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build out a basic implementation of Promises in Swift, and I need to be able to add functions to an array, but I'm not sure how to get that to work.

```
class Promise {
    var pending = []

    func resolve() -> Void {
    }

    func then(success: (Void -> Void)) -> Promise {
        // how do I add success to pending array?
        return self
    }
}

let p = Promise()
p.then({println("finished")})
```

What I'm finding is that the Swift Playground won't suggest `append` when I try to do something like this:

`self.pending.append(success)`

Which makes sense - Swift can't infer the type of `self.pending` - but that's where my problem lies. I'm not sure how to predefine an array of `(Void -> Void)` functions.

Is it possible to create an array of functions in Swift? I would assume so, with functions being first-class citizens.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but does the obvious `var pending: (Void->Void)[] = []` not work?

Comment: The Swift playground doesn't seem to like `var pending = (Void -> Void)[] = []`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's definitely possible, just initialize the array as:

```
var pending = Array<(Void -> Void)>()
```

or even a fancier

```
var pending = Array<()->()>()
```

or

```
var pending: [(Void->Void)] = []
```

or

```
var pending: [(()->())] = []
```

or

```
var penguins: [<(") <(")] = [] // kidding
```

Comment: or `(Void -> Void)[]`

Comment: (Void -> Void)[] doesn't work for me, but `Array<(Void -> Void)> works perfectly

Comment: If you want to get fancier you can use `Array<()->()>()`

Comment: @AlexWayne I meant `var array: (() -> ())[] = []` or `var array: (Void -> Void)[] = []`

Comment: @Sulthan, yep just added it.

Comment: Neat! Here's a fuller complete working example: https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/5d5c73a373b0c4839280

Comment: (()->())[] = [] not accepted as of Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

Comment: @AlexanderN yup, the array syntax changed over the beta period. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var pending: (() -> ())[]
```